# Using algorithm2e in English and French

Tags: latex

I am writing my thesis with two languages, i.e. English and French. I have written algorithm using algorithm2e in English. However, in one of the sections I also need to write algorithm in French. How can I achieve this? I mean I want to change all keywords in the algorithm into French in just one section and not the whole latex document.

Answer (score 4):

[`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) provides package options `french` and `frenchkw`. The former changes, amongst other things, the names associated with `\caption`s in `algorithm`. The latter provides French keywords that you can use.

If you want to use both English and French algorithms, then load the `algorithm2e` package under one option, and define the additional keywords as provided by the package. Below is a small example (I don't speak French):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

% French keywords:
\SetKwInput{KwRes}{R\'esultat}%
\SetKwIF{Si}{SinonSi}{Sinon}{si}{alors}{sinon si}{sinon}{fin si}%
\SetKwFor{Tq}{tant que}{faire}{fin tq}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms in English}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Algorithme}%
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwRes{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \Tq{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eSi{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms in French}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is the complete definition of content for English algorithms (taken from [`algorithm2e.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty)):

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{List of Algorithms}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Algorithm}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{algorithm}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmcflinename}{line}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@typo}{}%
\renewcommand{\@algocf@procname}{Procedure}%
\renewcommand{\@algocf@funcname}{Function}%
\renewcommand{\procedureautorefname}{procedure}%
\renewcommand{\functionautorefname}{function}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@languagechoosen}{english}%

\SetKwHangingKw{KwHData}{Data$\rightarrow$}
\SetKwInput{KwIn}{Input}%
\SetKwInput{KwOut}{Output}%
\SetKwInput{KwData}{Data}%
\SetKwInput{KwResult}{Result}%
\SetKw{KwTo}{to}
\SetKw{KwRet}{return}%
\SetKw{Return}{return}%
\SetKwBlock{Begin}{begin}{end}%
\SetKwRepeat{Repeat}{repeat}{until}%
%
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{end if}%
\SetKwSwitch{Switch}{Case}{Other}{switch}{do}{case}{otherwise}{end case}{end switch}%
\SetKwFor{For}{for}{do}{end for}%
\SetKwFor{ForPar}{for}{do in parallel}{end forpar}
\SetKwFor{ForEach}{foreach}{do}{end foreach}%
\SetKwFor{ForAll}{forall}{do}{end forall}%
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{do}{end while}%
```

Here is the complete definition of content for French algorithms (taken from [`algorithm2e.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty)):

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{Liste des Algorithmes}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Algorithme}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{algorithme}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmcflinename}{ligne}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@typo}{\ }%
\renewcommand{\@algocf@procname}{Proc\'edure}%
\renewcommand{\@algocf@funcname}{Fonction}%
\renewcommand{\procedureautorefname}{proc\'edure}%
\renewcommand{\functionautorefname}{fonction}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@languagechoosen}{french}%

\SetKwHangingKw{HDonnees}{Donnees$\rightarrow$}
\SetKwInput{Donnees}{Donn\'ees}%
\SetKwInput{Res}{R\'esultat}%
\SetKwInput{Entree}{Entr\'ees}%
\SetKwInput{Sortie}{Sorties}%
\SetKw{KwA}{\`a}%
\SetKw{Retour}{retourner}%
\SetKwBlock{Deb}{d\'ebut}{fin}%
\SetKwRepeat{Repeter}{r\'ep\'eter}{jusqu'\`a}%
%
\SetKwIF{Si}{SinonSi}{Sinon}{si}{alors}{sinon si}{sinon}{fin si}%
\SetKwSwitch{Suivant}{Cas}{Autre}{suivant}{faire}{cas o\`u}{autres cas}{fin cas}{fin d'alternative}%
\SetKwFor{Pour}{pour}{faire}{fin pour}%
\SetKwFor{PourPar}{pour}{faire en parall\`ele}{fin pour}%
\SetKwFor{PourCh}{pour chaque}{faire}{fin pour chaque}%
\SetKwFor{PourTous}{pour tous les}{faire}{fin pour tous}%
\SetKwFor{Tq}{tant que}{faire}{fin tq}%
```

If you use any of the definition containing an `@` (like `\renewcommand{\@algocf@procname}{Proc\'edure}`, for example), you'll have to surround the redefinition using a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764).